# Не выводятся элементы инфоблока при неавторизованном пользователе

Tags: linux, битрикс, авторизация, права

У меня такая проблема. Я работаю с сайтом на Битрикс Старт. При авторизации под админом все страницы выходят нормально. Но стоит разлогиниться, то для неавторизованного пользователя почти на всех страницах всплывает блок авторизации посреди контента даже. Это на тех страницах, где используются инфоблоки. Я ставил полные права для всех пользователей, в том числе и для неавторизованных. Для инфоблоков тоже ставил полные права. Но воз и ныне там.

После изменения прав на Полные для всех пользователей, в том числе неавторизованных, а также персонально для каждого компонента на странице "Список элементов инфоблока (Добавление элемента инфоблока)" сделал доступность его (их) для всех пользователей (там в параметрах есть это). То блок авторизации исчезает, но элементы ни одного инфоблока в компоненте "Добавление элементов инфоблока" не отображаются. Я использую этот компонент для вывода элементов инфоблока в одной странице на экран. Помогите, пожалуйста! Сайт на тестовике - на Линуксе.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

В настройках инфоблоков, выберите инфоблок, вкладка доступ. Для всех выберите => чтение

Comment: А почему я выбирал для всех "Полные права" - всё равно не работало? Ведь полные права - это лучше чем Чтение.

Comment: `Полные права` не будут работать если не авторизации, если бы была авторизация, хоть даже простой пользовател, то, он мог бы удалять/редактирова/добавлять элементы в ИБ. Доступ всегда `Чтение`.

Answer (score 0):

Я решил эту проблему заменой компонента "Список собственных элементов инфоблока" на "Список новостей" news.list. Теперь всё заработало.

Comment: Если хотите вывести список элементов из инфоблока, то, используйте news.list или через API ciblockelement:getlist